HAProxy SSL Health-Check
just need some help with my haproxy.cfg.
we want do loadbalance 1 URL (lbtest-portal.etask.de) on 2 Servers

(192.168.x.x) DNS (lbtest-portal1.etask.de)
(192.168.x.x) DNS (lbtest-portal2.etask.de)
both are hosted on IIS with activated SNI (there's more than this URL in the IIS)
the / URL redirect to xxx (301 Moved)
there is a redirect from http to https configured in the IIS
the LB work fine but we didnt get a health Check working

global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
        stats timeout 30s
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

        # Default SSL material locations
        #ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
        #crt-base /etc/ssl/private

        # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
        # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
        #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
        # An alternative list with additional directives can be obtained from
        #  https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=haproxy
        #ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
        #ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000

frontend stats
    mode http
    bind *:8404
    stats enable
    stats uri /stats
    stats refresh 10s
    stats admin if LOCALHOST

frontend fe_lbtest-portal_etask_de_443
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    bind *:443
    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
    tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }
    acl acl_lbtest-portal_etask_de req_ssl_sni -i lbtest-portal.etask.de
    use_backend be_lbtest-portal_etask_de_443 if acl_lbtest-portal_etask_de
    default_backend be_lbtest-portal_etask_de_443

backend be_lbtest-portal_etask_de_443
    mode tcp
    option log-health-checks
    default-server inter 10s fall 2 rise 5
    balance roundrobin
    server lbtest-portal1_etask_de_443 lbtest-portal1.etask.de:443 check verify none sni str(lbtest-portal1.etask.de)
    server lbtest-portal2_etask_de_443 lbtest-portal2.etask.de:443 check verify none sni str(lbtest-portal2.etask.de)

just tried many options like "option httpchk", "check-ssl", "option ssl-hello-chk", "check-sni" but nothing really want to work.
